# Not able to change URL path using $location service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change the entire url path using $location.url service, but it's not updating the path correctly.

E.g my path is

```
http://localhost:64621/module/commercial/#/company/98163780-4fa6-426f-8753-e05a67d48e54
```

and I want to change it to the

```
http://localhost:64621/module/sales/#/sales-company/98163780-4fa6-426f-8753-e05a67d48e54
```

my $location.url code is

```
$location.url('/module/sales/#/sales-company/98163780-4fa6-426f-8753-e05a67d48e54')
```

but still it's not properly working, it's not redirecting in the right way,
please let me know how i can achieve above functionality using $location service.

Comment: so what actually happens when you try?  error or path still changes?

Comment: you have multiple routes?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$window.location.href` for that, see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> **What does it not do?**
>   It does not cause a full page reload when the
>   browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use
>   the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `$location.path()` to change your url

like:

```
$location.path('/module/sales/#/sales-company/98163780-4fa6-426f-8753-e05a67d48e54');
```

you should enable HTML5 mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: enabled HTML5 mode ?